# No sound in every linux distribution,in aslamixer only one bar(master)

Tags: linux, audio, void-linux, alsamixer

Now i am using Void Linux,sound don't work,but when i type

```
$beep
```

Sound work,so i don't know where the problem.
Help please.

```
aplay -L

[bixbow@localhost ~]$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Alsamixer screenshot
[image: Alsamixer screenshot]

```
[bixbow@localhost ~]$ cat /proc/asound/cards


0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xa1320000 irq 127
```

Comment: While i press f6 nothing happened.

Comment: use `alsamixer --card 0` to access level controls for HDA Intel PCH device. Or get text equivalent information with `amixer -c 0`